# How do I program to get a list of engines my gpu has?

Tags: c++, windows, gpu, driver

I am trying to write a program similar to windows task manager.

I'm using `D3DKMTQueryAdapterInfo` `D3DKMTQueryStatistics` to get the status of the gpu.

but I can only get how many engines there are and not the name of each one.How could I get the engine's name based on his id.